# Do the <detail> and <summary> HTML tags which hide text until clicked have any effect on SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, html, search-engine-indexing, hidden-text

For example:

```
<details>
    <summary>
        short summary
    </summary>
        long details
</details>
```

Will Google treat "long details" normally or will it consider it less important, since it's hidden and will only be visible if users clicks/expands it?

Comment: Why it doesn't have any answer? its a relevant question imo

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, we can reasonably assume that even though the content isn't automatically visible, it will still affect the SEO rank for your site/page. Here's why:

Google's SEO algorithms is a combination of several aspects forming a typical webpage. The URL, title, meta description, keywords, links, content, (etc.,) all contribute to your rank. Too many keywords (which used to be a popular ploy) and it will hurt your ranking. The easiest way to prevent the problem is additional content to balance things out. The key is to create a page that provides solid information about the subject. SEO bots are looking at the entire page... even the parts that are waiting for user interaction(s) to activate them.